# Is it possible to boot OS X 10.6 from a USB drive with VMWare Fusion 3.1.3?

Tags: virtualization, vmware

I have USB drive with a partition containing OS X 10.6. I boot from this drive to use an app which doesn't run in Lion (Xcode 3.2.5). Rebooting is annoying.

Is it possible to boot a VMWare Fusion virtual machine directly from the USB drive (i.e. not 'forking' a virtual machine from it)? I have tried [Booting Operating System from USB Drive in VMware Fusion 3.x](http://www.ramgad.com/2010/08/21/booting-operating-system-from-usb-drive-in-vmware-fusion-3-x/) but it doesn't work for OS X (I changed the settings to OS X 10.6 Server instead of Windows 7). I have VMWare Fusion 3.1.3.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can create an image from the drive to use virtually? Or physically run the OS from that drive... virtually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 10.6 **Server**. It does not help to change the settings to 10.6 Server, you have to use 10.6 Server as operating system on the USB-Stick… or you can try some hacks, e.g. Hackintosh (search for it in Google) in a virtual environment but that's a little bit more complicated you can check

http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_Guides#VMware_Install_Guides

for this.